# Is heavier object falls slower according to special theory of relativity?

Tags: special-relativity

I'm newbie in physics, but have some idea want to know whether it is correct!
I saw some information about special theorey of relativity.

It just like says "when objects go faster it becomes more mass,but only reach near speed of light"

Now the question is, will the heavier object falls slower because it needs more kinetic energy to reach the same speed?

Comment: I came here expecting a good question that showed some misguided mathematics. This is like physics clickbait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A heavier object will gain more kinetic energy when falling than a lighter object but it has a higher potential energy to start with. It is actually not kinetic energy that is needed to fall but potential energy that is converted in kinetic energy while falling.

Generally, while the gravitational force on an object depends on it's gravitational mass, so does it's inertia (seen in Newton's law) and due to this its acceleration will not depend on mass. This is the equivalence principle in general relativity.

Comment: Should make it clearer that falling has nothing to do with mass. But yeah otherwise.